# Não estou conseguindo listar meus dados do SQLite

Tags: java, android

Boa noite, estou criando um aplicativo para controle financeiro, e estou testando o banco de dados, fazendo que ele me mostre os dados para eu ver se o evento **insert** está funcionando. Ao abrir a activity que mostra os dados, não aparece nada. Não sei se esta com problema no **array**, ou no click do **insert**, já revisei o código várias vezes e até comparei com um projeto antigo que tinha, e não estou conseguindo ver qual é o problema... Alguém poderia me ajudar?

DBSettings:

```
package project.welcomemoney.Base;

//Settings Base
public class DBSettings {
    private int id;
    private String NomeEmpresa;
    private int salario;
    private int gastoFixoTotal;
    private int gastoDiversoTotal;
    private int gastoTransporteTotal;
    private int totalFinal;

    public DBSettings(){/*NULL*/}

    public DBSettings(int id, String NomeEmpresa, int salario, int gastoFixoTotal, int gastoDiversoTotal, int gastoTransporteTotal, int totalFinal){
        this.id = id;
        this.NomeEmpresa = NomeEmpresa;
        this.salario = salario;
        this.gastoFixoTotal = gastoFixoTotal;
        this.gastoDiversoTotal = gastoDiversoTotal;
        this.gastoTransporteTotal = gastoTransporteTotal;
        this.totalFinal = totalFinal;
    }

    //Settings ID
    public int getId(){return id;}
    public void setId (int id) {this.id = id;}

    //Settings NomeEmpresa
    public  String getNomeEmpresa () {return NomeEmpresa;}
    public void setNomeEmpresa (String NomeEmpresa) {this.NomeEmpresa = NomeEmpresa;}

    //Settings Salario
    public int getSalario(){return salario;}
    public void setSalario(int salario){this.salario = salario;}

    //Settings Gasto fixo total

    public int getGastoFixoTotal(){return gastoFixoTotal;}
    public void setGastoFixoTotal(int gastoFixoTotal){this.gastoFixoTotal = gastoFixoTotal;}

    //Settings Gasto Diverso Total

    public int getGastoDiversoTotal(){return gastoDiversoTotal;}
    public void setGastoDiversoTotal(int gastoDiversoTotal) {this.gastoDiversoTotal = gastoDiversoTotal;}

    //Settings Gasto Transporte Total
    public int getGastoTransporteTotal(){return gastoTransporteTotal;}
    public void setGastoTransporteTotal(int gastoTransporteTotal) {this.gastoTransporteTotal = gastoTransporteTotal;}

    //Settings Total Final
    public int getTotalFinal() {return totalFinal;}
    public void setTotalFinal (int totalFinal) {this.totalFinal = totalFinal;}

    public String toString(){
        return "Nome da empresa: "
                +NomeEmpresa + " "
                + " Salário: "
                + salario + " "
                + " Seu Gasto Fixo: "
                + gastoFixoTotal + " "
                + " Seu Gasto Diverso: "
                + gastoDiversoTotal + " "
                +" Seu Total do mês: "
                + totalFinal;
    }

}
```

DBFunctionCRUD:

```
package project.welcomemoney.Base;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBFunctionCRUD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NAME_BASE = "Information";
    private static final int VERSION_BASE = 1;


    public DBFunctionCRUD(Context context) {
        super(context, NAME_BASE, null, VERSION_BASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase functionDB) {
        String sqlCreateTableInformation = "CREATE TABLE dados("
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NameCompany TEXT,"
                + "Salario INT,"
                + "GastoFixo INT,"
                + "GastoDiverso INT,"
                + "GastoTrasnporte INT,"
                + "TotalFinal INT" + ")";

        functionDB.execSQL(sqlCreateTableInformation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase functionDB, int BeforeVersion, int AfterVersion) {

        String sqlUpdateTableInformaction = "DROP TABLE dados";

        functionDB.execSQL(sqlUpdateTableInformaction);

        onCreate(functionDB);

    }


    public void insertInformation(DBSettings dados) {
        SQLiteDatabase base = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put("NameCompany", dados.getNomeEmpresa());
        insertValues.put("Salario", dados.getSalario());
        insertValues.put("GastoFixo", dados.getGastoFixoTotal());
        insertValues.put("GastoDiverso", dados.getGastoDiversoTotal());
        insertValues.put("GastoTransporte", dados.getGastoTransporteTotal());
        insertValues.put("TotalFinal", dados.getTotalFinal());

        base.insert("dados", null, insertValues);
        base.close();
    }

    public List<DBSettings> selectTodosResult() {
        List<DBSettings> listResult = new ArrayList<DBSettings>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        String sqlSelectTodosResult = "SELECT * FROM dados";

        Cursor allC = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectTodosResult, null);

        try {

            if (allC != null && allC.moveToFirst()) {
                allC.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    DBSettings InformationAll = new DBSettings();
                    InformationAll.setId(allC.getInt(0));
                    InformationAll.setNomeEmpresa(allC.getString(allC.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Salario")));
                    InformationAll.setGastoFixoTotal(allC.getInt(allC.getColumnIndexOrThrow("GastoFixo")));
                    InformationAll.setGastoDiversoTotal(allC.getInt(allC.getColumnIndexOrThrow("GastoDiverso")));
                    InformationAll.setGastoTransporteTotal(allC.getInt(allC.getColumnIndexOrThrow("GastoTransporte")));
                    InformationAll.setTotalFinal(allC.getInt(allC.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TotalFinal")));

                    listResult.add(InformationAll);

                } while (allC.moveToNext());

            }
        }catch (android.database.SQLException or){
            or.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.close();
        return listResult;
    }


    public void Delete(){
        SQLiteDatabase deleteBase = getReadableDatabase();
        String sqlSelectAllResult = "DELETE * FROM dados";
        Cursor listC = deleteBase.rawQuery(sqlSelectAllResult, null);
    }
}
```

Click do insert: **onClick defindo no xml**

```
public void salvarBancos (View view){
        DBSettings DBinsert = new DBSettings();
        DBinsert.setNomeEmpresa(EmpresaNome.getText().toString());
        DBinsert.setSalario(Integer.parseInt(receita.getText().toString()));
        DBinsert.setGastoFixoTotal(Integer.parseInt(gastoFixo.getText().toString()));
        DBinsert.setGastoFixoTotal(Integer.parseInt(metaConfig.getText().toString()));


        DBFunctionCRUD functionHelp = new DBFunctionCRUD(this);
        functionHelp.insertInformation(DBinsert);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Salvo com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

listando na array: **criei uma array personalizada como text1**

```
package project.welcomemoney;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

import project.welcomemoney.Base.DBFunctionCRUD;
import project.welcomemoney.Base.DBSettings;

public class MostrandoDadosTeste extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView TestList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrando_dados_teste);

        TestList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaTeste);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        DBFunctionCRUD funDB = new DBFunctionCRUD(this);
        List<DBSettings> listaTesteDB = funDB.selectTodosResult();
        ArrayAdapter<DBSettings> adp = new ArrayAdapter<DBSettings>(this, R.layout.array_personalizada, android.R.id.text1, listaTesteDB);
        TestList.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no botao ver resultado aparece no Logcat o seguinte erro:

```
04-24 21:00:15.849 2705-2705/project.welcomemoney E/SQLiteLog: (1) table dados has no column named GastoDiverso
04-24 21:00:15.849 2705-2705/project.welcomemoney E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting GastoDiverso=0 GastoTransporte=0 NameCompany=teste GastoFixo=121212 Salario=12145121 TotalFinal=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table dados has no column named GastoDiverso (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dados(GastoDiverso,GastoTransporte,NameCompany,GastoFixo,Salario,TotalFinal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at project.welcomemoney.Base.DBFunctionCRUD.insertInformation(DBFunctionCRUD.java:61)
        at project.welcomemoney.setting_home.salvarBancos(setting_home.java:40)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-24 21:00:15.904 2705-2788/project.welcomemoney V/RenderScript: 0xa1c3d000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
04-24 21:00:15.961 2705-2705/project.welcomemoney E/SQLiteLog: (1) table dados has no column named GastoDiverso
04-24 21:00:15.961 2705-2705/project.welcomemoney E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting GastoDiverso=0 GastoTransporte=0 NameCompany=teste GastoFixo=121212 Salario=12145121 TotalFinal=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table dados has no column named GastoDiverso (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dados(GastoDiverso,GastoTransporte,NameCompany,GastoFixo,Salario,TotalFinal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at project.welcomemoney.Base.DBFunctionCRUD.insertInformation(DBFunctionCRUD.java:61)
        at project.welcomemoney.setting_home.salvarBancos(setting_home.java:40)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Existe um erro na *query* `sqlCreateTableInformation`. A coluna `TotalFinal` não possui um tipo específico.

Verifique e defina um tipo para esta coluna, se {`INTEGER`, `TEXT`, `BOOLEAN`, `DOUBLE`, `ETC`. }

Veja um exemplo de como deve ficar caso seja do tipo `double`:

```
TotalFinal double
```

*Query* completa:

```
String sqlCreateTableInformation = "CREATE TABLE dados("
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "NameCompany TEXT,"
                + "Salario INT,"
                + "GastoFixo INT,"
                + "GastoDiverso INT,"
                + "GastoTrasnporte INT,"
                + "TotalFinal DOUBLE" + ")";
```

**EDIÇÃO**

Este erro:

> (1) table dados has no column named GastoDiverso

Quer dizer que não possui a coluna `GastoDiverso` na sua tabela. Você esqueceu de colocar uma virgula antes dessa coluna, então por isso o erro:

Altere a linha:

```
"GastoFixo INT"
```

para:

```
"GastoFixo INT,"
```

Comment: Opa... Foi um vacilo meu, obrigado por avisar, mas o meu problema ainda continua :(, ele não aparece os dados do banco na array

Comment: @Nathan sabe informar qual erro está dando?

Comment: Está dando o seguinte conflito : - `Error inserting GastoDiverso=0 GastoTransporte=0 NameCompany=teste GastoFixo=121212 Salario=12145121 TotalFinal=0
                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table dados has no column named GastoDiverso (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO dados(GastoDiverso,GastoTransporte,NameCompany,GastoFixo,Salario,TotalFinal) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)` **Irei adicionar na perguta o erro completo**

Comment: @Nathan encontrei mais um erro... tente novamente. ^^

Comment: Era um erro, mas ainda continua dando problema, mas agora sei que é algo que esta dando "falha" na coluna GastoDiverso... Obrigado, mas se conseguir ajudar mais fico grato colega.

Comment: @Nathan e agora qual é o erro?  hehee

Comment: Então a mensagem e a mesma, dizendo que a coluna GastoDiverso não existe, ai eu eliminei para ver se funcionava e deu certo, creio que pode estar causando e na hora de setar ele no arquivo **setting_home** pois os campos que estão setado estão sendo usados como **NomeEmpresa, GastoFixo, Salario...** e o GastoDiverso não esta sendo usado, por isso o problema talvez, pois nos outros lugares o nome GastoDiverso está corrento... Bom talvez pode ser isso, sou iniciante ainda haha.

Answer (score 0):

O nome da sua coluna na criação do banco está com erro de digitação:

GastoTrasnporte

E você está tentando inserir dados na coluna que deveria ser o nome certo

GastoTransporte

Comment: Outra sugestão, tente trabalhar com Content Provider. O acesso aos dados fica mais isolado e controlado e bem menos suscetível a erros de digitação como esse, até porque se você mudar a estrutura da base, não terá quase impacto algum no código da aplicação, pois só precisará mexer na classe de Contrato do Content Provider. Outra vantagem de trabalhar com Content Provider você conseguir listar os dados numa ListView ou RecyclerView usando CursorLoaders para manter a lista sempre sincronizada com a base.

Comment: Opa, gostei da dica, vou me informar sobre isso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse curso gratuito. Muito bom: https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845/